# Displaying nested python dictionary in html table

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, html-table

I have a nested python dictionary. I want to display this in a html table. I am passing the dictionary as a context variable to access it in html.
However, I cannot get it to display the way I want. The way I want to display it is to have the keys as columns and then the values as the data for the rows.
I have kind of got half way there:

**Dictionary:**

```
dict = {1: {'name': 'John', 'age': '27', 'height': '160'},
          2: {'name': 'Marie', 'age': '22', 'height': '170'}}
```

**Html:**

```
<table class="u-full-width" id="table2">
<thead >
    <tr>

    </tr>
  </thead>
 <tbody>
    {% for key,value in dict_items.items %}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="text-align:center">{{ key }}</th>
        <td style="text-align:center">{{ value }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

**current result**

[image]

Comment: How have you got halfway there? Where is your *code*?

Comment: After taking some time to think about it, It sounds like you want to use the `jinja` library for this. Is the second example an HTML template? It's a bit confusing what it's there for. I would say try converting that to jinja syntax, and you should get the desired output as html.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing nested dictionary to a HTML fle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597945/writing-nested-dictionary-to-a-html-fle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if that is Django change this line

```
 <td style="text-align:center">{{ value }}</td>
```

to

```
 <td style="text-align:center">{{ value.name }}</td>
 <td style="text-align:center">{{ value.age }}</td>
 <td style="text-align:center">{{ value.height }}</td>
```

if that helped you, please don't forget to accept this as the correct answer.